# change default icons of particular file types

Tags: icons

How can I change the default icons for a particular file extension type , for example, the .tex file?

I have tried with

> assogiate

, but it cannot do the job, it seems

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity desktop manager.

Comment: What desktop manager are you using? KDE, GNOME, Unity, LXDE, other?

Comment: you need to change the default icon on `usr/share/icons/[icon theme]`.

Comment: @Braiam I am using Unity

Comment: @JoãoAndré How shall I do that ?

Comment: @Braiam It is not duplicate it seems as the above link changes the overall icon theme